# Not able to select future date in calender using Appium Java

Tags: java, eclipse, appium, appium-android

I have to create a future dated transfer and for that I need to select a date which is ahead of today's date. Index is '0' for all dates (past or future). Date field is 'TextView' so sendkeys doesn't work.

[image]

Following is the snapshot of calendar dates displayed when user click on 'Date' field

[image]

I want to select a date which is 5 days ahead of today's date. Only today's date has different resource-id but for rest of dates(past or future) resource-id is same. The only difference visible in Node details is for 'FrameLayout' is that values for 'clickable' & 'enabled' is false for past dates but for current and future dates it is true. So I tried an xpath with 'enabled' and/or 'clickable' but that is not working.

I am stuck with this issue for last two days. It would be great if I receive any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried `xpath` with text?

Comment: Imran, in that case every time before running the script I would have to change the value of text in xpath.

Comment: Are either of the ancestors - the RelativeLayout or the FrameLayout clickable?

Comment: For past dates FrameLayout clickable is false and for today's & future dates FrameLayout clickable is true. Value of clickable is false for old and future dates in RelativeLayout.